# Проверка размера файла перед загрузкой

Tags: javascript, файлы

```
                    <script>
                    function uploadFile(){

                        var file = document.getElementById("resume").files[0];
                        if(file.size > (1024 * 1024 * 20)){

                            alert('Размер файла не должен превышать 20 мб');
                            location.reload();

                        }else{
                           var form = document.getElementById("upload_file");
                           form.submit(); 
                        }
                    }
                </script>
```

Пытаюсь реализовать загрузку файла. Перед загрузкой хочу узнать размер. В интернете куча примеров, но у меня почему-то вечно такая ошибка происходит

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Что делать, как исправлять ?

Comment: у `document.getElementById("resume")` нет свойства `files`. Покажите html.

Comment: приложи свою html разметку и когда вызывается данная фунция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mожете не показывать разметку :).

У Вас в html два (или больше) DOM-элемента с `id="resume"`, причем первый из них - не `input` с `type="file"`.

*Реклама:*

**"Удаленная диагностика при недостатке информации."**

*Находим вещи, домашних животных, людей - по фотографиям тех мест, где они когда-нибудь побывали. Недорого.*

Comment: экстрасенс детектед)

Comment: "Он чинит радиоприемники, думая!" Ричард Ф.Фейнман http://www.metodolog.ru/01214/01214.html